# Import only defined files on first commit

Tags: svn

I have an external subversion repository, which is empty now. Let's call it http://www.example.com/svn

From my local machine, where my working directory is, I'd like to export only defined files (not whole project) to the repository. I created a text file "svn-list.txt" where I store a list of files to synchronize.

How do I do something like:

```
svn import -m "Importing" --targets svn-list.txt . http://www.example.com/svn
```

Of course **--targets** param doesn't exist for import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `svn add` to add files of svn-list.txt to version control and schedul them for next commit

use `svn propset svn:ignore` to ignore files that are not in your svn-list.txt

use `svn commit` to commit everiything to the repository

Comment: Thanks A4L. But, the files are not under version control yet.

Comment: after the commit ignored files will not be commited and thus not versioned, olny the properties are commited.

Comment: Ok. But how do I make working copy from the directory if the repo is empty. Can I simply do svn co http://www.example.com/svn public_html ?

Comment: Ok, since your repository is empty you have to first create a directory on the server for your project 'svn mkdir http://www.example.com/svn/myproject'. than checkt it out 'svn checkout http://www.example.com/svn/myproject working_directory', after that you can proceed with the 3 steps above.